# Simple form builder

Tags: 8, forms, webforms, emails

I want to allow website managers(editors) to build custom forms:

- Editors should be able to create a form with a few text fields and specify the recipient emails.
- Form should send email with fields content
- The forms should be simply managed
- The forms submissions should be stored and listed in backend.

Currently there are few options, but none of them can be used by website managers. See the reasons below:

Contact module (core):

1. I do not want to allow editors to manage entity fields, it is overhead.
2. The module exports forms as a configuration.

[Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)

1. The UI is too complex for editors. There are a lot of available fields, some pages and settings like access, ajax usage and additional logic.
2. The module exports forms as a configuration.

[Eform (Entity form)](https://www.drupal.org/project/eform) is unsupported.

Currently we trying to do it with webform. We are trying to hide the unnecessary settings with form alter :-D Also we are trying to avoid webforms configuration export/import.

How do you create form builders for website managers(editors)?

Comment: Webform is basically the defacto solution here. It does everything you listed, and more.

Comment: thx, @Kevin the webform is listed in my question. As said it is a too complex for editors; also it requires configuration export. I am looking for a way more simpler solution.

Comment: It would be a lot quicker to hide what you don’t want from Webform than implement your requirements from scratch, maybe consider going full-on with that approach. I say “from scratch” because it’s hard to imagine someone building a competing, simpler version of Webform at this point, and if you’re ruling out editors managing fields, that’s pretty much any core-based solution out of the window as well

Comment: EntityForm also has a different purpose (IMO) - but without the completeness of Rules in D8 like D7, that module could only be half as powerful as it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the guy that created the complex Webform UI. For my clients, I disable any unneeded elements, handlers, and exporters. I also use hook_form_alter() to hide (via #access: FALSE) any feature that is not needed. I also have people create forms from Templates which have form behaviors and email handling preconfigured. You can also use hook_webform_create() to define reasonable defaults.

People are using the [Config Split module](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) to [manage webforms (and blocks) configuration](https://www.drupal.org/node/2883110).

BTW, one day I hope someone will sponsor a Webform sub-module that allows site administrators to pick and choose which Webform features and element properties should be available to site builders.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's what we were doing today: creating an internal module simplify_webform + config_split. I will leave the question open for now, let's see if there will be any more suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the module. We simplified the module, not it looks more clean for the editors.

Comment: @jrockowitz Any news about the sub-module you mentioned?